# warning: 'Systems3 View Controller' has both its 'View' and 'NIB Name' properties set. This configuration is not supported

Tags: ios4

I got this warning in title when I built the app to device(iPad). 
And  the Mainwindow has : object, Files owner, first responder, view controller and window.

Can anybody help whats the matter?

Yours

Miska

Answer (score 0):

The thing happens when you have two declarations in defferent xib files. For example you delete TextController.xib file, but declaration stil exists. And you can see ie in your Interface builder.
Just take a look on you View Controller "Loaded from TextController.xib". You can delete the declaration and create new one. It should help.